# SQL Pivot Query for pivot values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
iItemKey    Qty FreeQty Unit  TaxCatKey TaxVal
    7        1    1      1        1      4.00
    7        1    1      1        1      1.00
```

I need output as

```
iItemKey    Qty FreeQty Unit  TaxCatKey   VAT  A.VAt
    7        1    1      1        1       4.00   1.00
```

Here is my query. But i get VAT and A.Vat values as Null

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT     T_ItemRequestSub.iItemKey, T_ItemRequestSub.Qty, T_ItemRequestSub.FreeQty, T_ItemRequestSub.Unit, T_ItemRequestSub.TaxType, 
                   M_Mt_TaxCategorySub.iTaxCatKey ,  M_Mt_TaxCategorySub.iTaxVal
FROM         T_ItemRequestSub INNER JOIN
                      T_ItemRequest ON T_ItemRequestSub.iReqKey = T_ItemRequest.iKey INNER JOIN
                      M_Mt_TaxCategory ON T_ItemRequestSub.TaxType = M_Mt_TaxCategory.iKey INNER JOIN
                      M_Mt_TaxCategorySub ON M_Mt_TaxCategory.iKey = M_Mt_TaxCategorySub.iTaxCatKey where T_ItemRequestSub.iKey = 2)
SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT ( sum (iTaxVal) FOR TaxType IN ( 
       [Vat],
       [A.Vat]
      ) ) AS pvt
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the output?

Comment: What if there are 3 rows in your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only distinct value is TaxVal so I suspect you are trying to do following:

```
WITH Src AS --Your source table
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4.00),
    (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.00)
    )T(iItemKey, Qty, FreeQty, Unit, TaxCatKey, TaxVal)
)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT iItemKey, Qty, FreeQty, Unit, TaxCatKey, TaxVal, CASE WHEN TaxVal = 1.00 THEN 'VAT' ELSE 'A.VAT' END Col
    FROM Src
) T
PIVOT (MAX(TaxVal) FOR Col IN ([VAT], [A.VAT])) P
```